# Should I reject an edit suggestion as an attempt to reply or approve on basics of post improvement?

Tags: discussion

I just reviewed this [edit suggestion](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/56384). The user claims to *update to contain information about non-US banks* and he rather added quite good information. I rejected the edit suggestion as an *attempt to reply*. However I read that Stack Exchange encourages users to edit old -even accepted and highly upvoted/appreciated- answers that are obsolete for nowadays.

Given these 2 contradictory facts, I wonder if I did wrong by rejecting the edit or not ? Or maybe since the question is moderated as out-of topic and thus any interaction with the answers must be rejected anyway ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The help section lists the [common reasons why a post should be edited](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

None of them seems to match this edit suggestion. In particular, this edit:

- changes the post meaning,
- and is not updating obsolete content (I understand "obsolete" as meaning something which deprecates or becomes invalid over time, this has nothing to do with geographical discrepancies).

As a comment however it would be very welcome, but I actually guess that the edit was used here as a workaround to the limitation affecting comments: *when one does not have enough reputation to leave a comment, let's just edit the post directly!*

Comment: Thank you very much wise man. The 6th point you mentioned is already a full answer. Regards

Comment: I agree that a comment would work well, but couldn't that edit fall under **add addendums / updates as the post ages**?  Or would it be considered not "aged" enough?

Comment: @raz: Could you pinpoint what *exactly* was aging in the original post? For me it is still as current today as it was when posted 2 months ago, its content doesn't seem obsolete nor invalid.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf I was looking at it as an additional addendum.  The question/answer itself definitely isn't aged.  While not obsolete or invalid it seems like it might be incomplete.  Which in that case I suppose really means a new answer should have been provided over an edit.  Now I'm just thinking while typing.  I agree with your answer.